# CSS Columns without bullets

Tags: css

I have a simple list that displays fine in a single column. I have "text-decoration: none" set for the list items. When I add column-count: 2, the second column displays bullets. Any suggestions for a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:
`list-style-type:none;`

That is, as long as you don't want any bullet points on your `<li>`.

Example:

```html
<style>
/* code to make <li> horizontal horizontal */

/* code to remove bullet points from all <li> inside of <ul> tags*/
ul > li { list-style-type: none; }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Or you may use the `<table>` and achieve this as well. Here is a link that may be of interest regarding tables.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp